# When you write regex engines how do you know if question marks `?` mean zero or one of if they refer to non-capturing groups?

Tags: syntax, compilers, regex

When you write regulair expression (regex) engines, how do you tell ....

> if `?` means `zero or one`

...or if...

> `?` means `begin non-capturing group`

Some examples of regular expressions are shown below:

```
(https?|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?
(?:https?|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?
```

Answer (score 6):

Logically, the `?` symbol should not exist without a preceding group or character. This is evident as most Regular Expression Engines will error when presented with only a `?`, or with an Expression that begins with `?`.

When implementing an engine, one must keep reference to the previous token for the purposes of counting operators such as `?` or `*`.

Thus, when an engine encounters a `?`, if there is no preceding token, and they are in a group, then they can be sure that this is a special group, which then depends on the characters following the `?`. `?:` for non-capturing, `?#` for comments, and so on.

Essentially, `?` can perform two different things by simply being aware of the context in which it appears, rather than processing it "in a vacuum".